# How to get "geolocation" permission inside sandbox of chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app, sandbox, google-geolocation

I have a chrome app with permissions set one of which is geolocation.
It have a sandbox index.html
I want to get user location from that index.html. Is there any way I can get geolocation from that page.

```
function success(position){

}
function error(){
  console.log('unable to track user location now')
}
var id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

gives error user denied location.
I did not see pop up this page is requestiong geolocation permisison

Comment: It's always possible to use messaging to the main window which will access the API and post the results back.

Comment: That is what I am doing right now. Was looking for a better solution say I am tracking the user location continuously is it ok to fire so many post to get current location

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox does not get the privileges that the app is granted (that's exactly the point of a sandbox), and the Chrome App UI does not allow permission prompts.

Therefore, a sandboxed page can never get that permission. You will need to perform geolocation from a non-sandboxed page and [communicate with the sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval#pass_result).